# How to add content to a file, but start from row 4?

Tags: php

I have an xml template that currently looks like this:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tv>
<channel id="560"><display-name lang="he">560</display-name></channel>

**** The content I save later will start from line 4 (here) ****

</tv>
```

My PHP file is dragging content from other files:

```
<?php
file_get_contents("http://website.com/guide?1");
file_get_contents("http://website.com/guide?2");
file_get_contents("http://website.com/guide?3");
file_get_contents("http://website.com/guide?4");
file_get_contents("http://website.com/guide?5");
```

What I want to do is to add the content to the file,

But start from line 4 & without deleting the last line

UPDATE:

```
<tv>

//I want the content to stick to here, before the /tv root

</tv>  //Sould be the last line

<channel id="861"><display-name lang="he">861</display-name></channel>

<programme start="20180127013500 +0200" stop="20180127020000 +0200" channel="861">
<title lang="he">היום בלילה</title>
<desc lang="he">גורי אלפי מסכם מדי לילה את אירועי היום בתכנית בידור מצחיקה ובועטת: האנשים שעשו את החדשות, פוליטיקאים, סטנדאפיסטים ומוזיקאים. כ' סמויות.</desc>
</programme>
```

Comment: Could you describe (or post an example) how look the files you want to insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your files are also XML compliant, you can do that (otherwise, try to load the remote files using the `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile` method in place of `DOMDocument::load` method that is for XML only):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('template.xml');
$root = $dom->documentElement;

for ($i=1; $i<6; $i++) {
    $domi = new DOMDocument;
    $domi->load('http://website.com/guide?'.$i);
    $rooti = $domi->documentElement;
    $node = $dom->importNode($rooti, true);
    $root->appendChild($node);
}

$result = $dom->saveXML();
```

Note that if your remote files are not loaded, you can set stream parameters (in particular the user agent) using [`libxml_set_streams_context`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-set-streams-context.php).

Comment: Thanks,I'll check as soon as I'm on the computer, and I'll update.

Comment: @phong: if you experiment encoding problems, load your remote files using `file_get_contents` and replace `$domi->load('...` with `$domi->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . $filecontent);` (to preserve the UTF-8 encoding).

Comment: Thank you, the code worked for me. But a question, how do I do that it will add the content before the last line?
I updated the post

Comment: @phong: perhaps you didn't give the real structure of your template, because my code does what it is supposed to do. See this [demo](https://3v4l.org/QYF0j). If your template file is different (*tv* isn't the root element), try to change `$root = $dom->documentElement;` to `$root = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tv')->item(0);`